# Detecting clicks on pictures in WKWebView?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that navigates to facebook, instagram. Is there any way to detect whether a photo was pressed within the webView and to download the picture and present it in a modal view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [user script](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkuserscript) to the webview that handles long press on images. User scripts are JavaScript code that runs at the time of your choosing. Using these scripts, you can, using a specific Apple API, pass data to your native code and do what you want.